# Integration of arcsin polynomial

Tags: integration, trigonometry, trigonometric-integrals

$\int4\sin^{-1}\sqrt{y} - (\sin^{-1}\sqrt{y})^2  dy$

I've tried doing integration by parts but the problem seems to only get more complex. I've also tried with the online integral calculator which yields a very long and tedious expression, is there any other simpler way i can approach this question?

Comment: Try the change $y=\sin^2(t)$ and then by parts.

Answer (score 0):

Well, start by subbing $y=u^2$; the integral is then

$$2 \int du \, u \left (4 \arcsin{u} - \arcsin^2{u} \right ) $$

Integrate by parts; the integral is equal to

$$4 u^2 \arcsin{u} - u^2 \arcsin^2{u} - 4 \int du \frac{u^2}{\sqrt{1-u^2}} + 2 \int du \, \frac{u^2 \arcsin{u}}{\sqrt{1-u^2}} $$

The first integral is easily done using a sub of $u=\sin{t}$; you get

$$4 \int dt \, \sin^2{t} = 2 t - \sin{t} \cos{t} + C = 2 \arcsin{u} - 2 u \sqrt{1-u^2} + C$$

Use the same sub for the second integral and integrate by parts to get:

$$\begin{align}2 \int dt \, t \, \sin^2{t} &= t^2- t \sin{t} \cos{t} - \int dt \, t + \int dt \, \sin{t} \cos{t} \\ &= \frac12 t^2 -  t \sin{t} \cos{t} + \frac12 \sin^2{t} + C' \\ &=  \frac12 \arcsin^2{u} -  u \sqrt{1-u^2} \arcsin{u} + \frac12 u^2 + C'\end{align}$$

Putting this all together, I get as the antiderivative being sought

$$4y \arcsin{\sqrt{y}}  - y \arcsin^2{\sqrt{y}} - 2 \arcsin{\sqrt{y}}+2 \sqrt{y (1-y)} +  \frac12 \arcsin^2{\sqrt{y}} -  \sqrt{y (1-y)} \arcsin{\sqrt{y}} + \frac12 y + C''$$

where $C''=-C+C'$.